# MeteorJS insert method not inserting

Tags: javascript, mongodb, web-applications, meteor, insert

I'm trying to write an app to do real time messaging as a learning tool. I've been googling for the past 4 and a half hours trying to figure out why my insert method isn't working. It doesn't throw any errors, it simply doesn't do the actual insert.

Here's the code for it:
JS client:

```
Template.input.events({
        "keypress .input": function(event, template){
            if(event.which == 13){
                event.preventDefault();

                var user = Meteor.user();
                var message = template.find(".input").value;
                alert(Meteor.call("insert", user.username, message));

                template.find(".input").value = ""; 

            }
        }
    });
```

JS Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
      'insert':function(username, message){
            Messages.insert({
                'message': message,
                'user': Meteor.userId(),
                'username': username,
                'timestamp': new Date()
            });
            return "success";
      },
      'find': function(){
            Messages.find({}, {sort: {timestamp:-1}});
      }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<template name="input">
    <div id="input">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Message..." id="message" />
    </div>
</template>
```

I've checked using the console to confirm that nothing is being added.

Comment: do you still have autopublish and insecure on? Can you do an insert from the browser console?

Comment: Are you checking for the existence of your new message document from the browser console or from Mongo directly (via `meteor mongo` in a shell)? Odds are your document is being written but you're not publishing and subscribing to the messages collection.

Comment: I have autopublish on, but I don't have secure on. When I try to insert from the developer console, it says insert failed, access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs fine, and the items are saved in the DB. Just as jorjordandan and Michel mentioned it's probably caused by your publications.

An easy way to check this is to simply log what's stored. Add some logging. Since server methods always have access to all collections you can see what's actually stored.

```
  'insert':function(username, message){
        var id = Messages.insert({
            'message': message,
            'user': Meteor.userId(),
            'username': username,
            'timestamp': new Date()
        });
        console.log('Inserted id: ' + id);
        var insertedMessage = Messages.findOne(id);
        console.log(insertedMessage);
        return "success";
  },
```

Also, as a side-note, you might reconsider posting username as a string to the server method, depending on what you're after. This can easily be manipulated by the client.
Instead you could fetch the user on server-side.

> Meteor.user().username

Just make sure that the user is actually logged on, or check if Meteor.user() is undefined.

Comment: I'm making this more as a teaching tool, and I'm going to edit it and rearrange a bunch of stuff before I ever apply it to anything I would put my name on. I know that I would have to sanitize an input, I'm just trying to get this to work. Thank you for the advice, though. I checked the database through the shell, and messages is not being populated. I also alerted on the message, and as soon as it goes to the server side, it seems to disappear into the aether. Also the user system is working perfectly fine. It's just this message collection.

Comment: Oh shit, it was actually logging it, but I was assuming it was logging it in the browser console. It was logging the messages in the terminal that's running the meteorjs script

Comment: I typed messages instead of Messages when querying the db. I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Subnatural -> Good luck with your project. Glad I could help.